# Ubercart file downloads - group user's file downloads by product

Tags: ubercart, files

Setting up a site using Drupal 6 and Ubercart (UC) to sell video downloads. I've configured UC as required to sell the file downloads and that all works. However, when a user visits their profile and views their file downloads, I need that page to display files on a per product grouping.

For example, a customer purchases product A, which includes three files. They then purchase product B, which includes two files. I need the user file downloads page to display the five files in two groups, Product A files and Product B files.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue with a combination of:

- Advanced profile
- Views
- Node access

I used the Node Access module to create products that were nodes. Only users that had purchased a particular node could see it.

I used Views to create a view that displayed all nodes of the relevant type, including the files attached to them, in a table. The view will only display items that the user viewing it has permissions to see (i.e. those that they have purchased).

I used Advanced Profile to create a new profile page that displayed the view outlined above.